# How to use XAML resource of SolidColorBrush in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I am defining resources in my App.XAML file:

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ActivePanelBackgBrush" Color="#FF77FF83"/>

 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NonActivePanelBackgBrush" Color="#FFFF7777"/>
```

In my C# code I would like to set the background of a Grid to that color. How do I do that?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get objects from Resources in App.xaml like that:

```
 var brush = Application.Current.Resources["NonActivePanelBackgBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
```

And use it where you want:

```
 Grid1.Background = brush;
```

Alternatively you can use `FindResource`.
However, WinRT seemed to be missing the `FindResource` function which is  familiar from WPF.  You can use [this](http://janne.rautiola.fi/portfolio/findresource-extension-method-for-winrt/) extension method.( sadly I have not tested it yet)

```
Grid1.Background = FindResource("NonActivePanelBackgBrush") as SolidColorBrush;
```

Comment: Getting this runtime error:
'this.Resources["ActivePanelBackgBrush"]' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Comment: @eitanbarazani Have you tried with `FindResource` method?

Comment: the Application.Current.Resources works fine :) I think the FindResource isn't a WinRT call.

Comment: @eitanbarazani I am glad it worked. Yes, you are right about `FindResource` in WinRT. I hav edited my answer witha link to the possible solution about calling FindResource in WinRT.